# 3 Monitors on a Notebook

Tags: laptop, multiple-monitors

I would like to use 3 screens on my Dell Inspiron 1720

So On the laptop built in screen have that as one, and then have 2 more screens.

The catch is, that I want to play racing games with this set-up.  So that my main screen is the focus area (the front window if you will) and the other 2 screens will be used for peripheral vision, on the side.

The software that I use (LFS.net) does support multiple screens.  However the notebook can have the main screen on, and another external screen.

So I would need to split this "second" monitor output, to 2 screens, the one to the left of the main monitor, and the other one to the right.  Is this possible?

Is there perhaps a external card / docking station solution that could help with this?

Any advice or ideas is greatly appreciated.

Best Regards
Rihan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is either a [Matrox TripleHeadToGo](http://www.matrox.com/graphics/en/products/gxm/th2go/) or a [Matrox DualHeadToGo](http://www.matrox.com/graphics/en/products/gxm/dh2go/).

You can't do directly what you want (split the monitor either side of the internal screen) but if you don't mind the two external screens being to either the left or right of your Laptop screen then you could use a Matrox DualHeadToGo.

Alternatively, you could ignore your internal laptop screen when docked, and just use one (very wide) external screen, the TripleHeadToGo will split that screen over 3 monitors.

The set up I've been intending to get running is three 1680x1050 monitors side by side, running a single 5040*1050 output from my laptop.

Answer (score 0):

Just my two cents

Look at this article from Scott Hanselmann at

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/GetThosePixelsWorkingForYou.aspx

Maybe this will give you pointers or may serve your purpose.

Comment: Those solutions I am aware of but they do not support a 3d application :(