# How can you connect three external displays to a laptop with only one vga or dvi port and plenty of usb ports?

Tags: laptop, multiple-monitors

I have had some success with usb docks like this [Universal Docking Station by Kensington](http://us.kensington.com/html/17444.html) to connect one external display to my laptop while using the onboard vga port for another display. But that's only two displays and I'm shooting for three. All I do is develop software and work in Photoshop... no games. For the sake of discussion, we can assume a Thinkpad or equivalent laptop with Windows 7 (I'm hoping for a platform-agnostic solution). How could I do this?

UPDATE: Question #128311 talks about almost the same thing, but the only solution was a Matrox TripleHeadToGo. I don't like that solution because the matrol box merely makes windows think that it has one desktop that is x*3 pixels wide (where x is single desktop width). One problem with this is that the taskbar stretches across all monitors and always starts on the left-most display. Also, try telling a video to go full-screen... As far as the OS knows, full-screen is x*3 pixels wide (e.g. your video spans three monitors).

UPDATE: I should be able to use my existing displays, asuming my displays can run on VGA and/or DVI.

Comment: What happens when you follow the same process you used to get the intial monitor to show up via USB?

Comment: It this the same questions as http://superuser.com/questions/128311/3-monitors-on-a-notebook

Comment: @MichaelKay: Maybe but the answer was not the one I wanted. I'll update the question to note the difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

USB port, meet [video adapter](http://www.usbgear.com/USB-Video-Card.html).

Comment: Awesome. That's going to work perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could use USB-based monitors such as the one at:

http://www.thinkgeek.com/computing/usb-gadgets/bfa3/

Comment: Obviously this is a valid answer, but I'd rather not have to purchase all new displays.