# Is there a way to connect Dell Latitude E4310 with one VGA to 2 external monitors without using docking station?

Tags: networking, laptop, multiple-monitors, laptop-display

Is there a way to connect Dell Latitude E4310 with one VGA to 2 external monitors without using a docking station?

Comment: [How can you connect three external displays to a laptop with only one vga or dvi port and plenty of usb ports?](http://superuser.com/questions/129300/how-can-you-connect-three-external-displays-to-a-laptop-with-only-one-vga-or-dvi?rq=1)

Answer (score 2):

There are usb to vga adapters which are basically external "graphics cards" . They require software to be installed but aren't very expensive, very portable, and pretty easy to use.

http://www.startech.com/AV/USB-Video-Adapters/USB-VGA-Adapter-External-Video-Card-PC-Mac~USB2VGAPRO2