# Is it possible to connect 3 monitors with Dell Inspiron N5010

Tags: multiple-monitors

I've a Windows Machine, Dell Inspiron N5010.
I've 3 different monitors: the laptop main display, and two other Dell Monitors.
I've been using one monitor connected to the VGA port and I was wondering if I would be able to connect the second monitor to its HDMI port and use all the 3 displays.

Is it possible or do I need to buy a separate graphics card??

Comment: This is very similar to several other questions. Answers which you might find useful include http://superuser.com/questions/128311/3-monitors-on-a-notebook/128825#128825 and http://superuser.com/questions/656/connecting-2-external-monitors-to-a-laptop/25681#25681

Answer (score 2):

Try it out.

*But probably **no**.*

From what I see around after a quick search and the specifications on the N5010 the graphics card in the laptop likely doesn't have the capability/strength to output to more than 1 device, or even just the drivers for the card might not support it.

If you did want to achieve this 1 option would be to upgrade the graphics card in the laptop (but this might be costly), as the laptop doesn't have the capability to have two graphics cards.

Another option after another quick search is an "external graphics cards" but I'm not familiar enough to comment, on cost effectiveness / performance / stability of this option.

Comment: An external USB video adapter is fine for anything except extremely high resolution screens or fast moving video, and is by far the easiest solution.  Most laptops don't have upgradable graphics cards.